# How do I limit the Tokio threadpool to a certain number of native threads?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, mio

What's the correct way of limiting the Tokio (v 0.1.11) threadpool to `n` OS native threads, where `n` is an arbitrary number, preferably configurable at runtime?

As far as I can tell, it's possible to use Tokio in single threaded mode using using `tokio_current_thread::block_on_all` instead of `tokio::run` and `tokio_current_thread::spawn` instead of `tokio::spawn`.

I'd like a similar solution but for `n >= 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build a Tokio `Runtime` object using [`tokio::runtime::Builder`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.11/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html).  The builder offers a [`core_threads()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.11/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.core_threads) method that can be used to configure the number of threads, e.g.

```
let mut rt = runtime::Builder::new()
    .core_threads(4)
    .build()
    .unwrap();
```

You can then use `rt.spawn(some_future)` to run a future on this runtime.

Comment: May I ask, if you know, why does the `tokio_current_thread` crate exist if this runtime build is already a thing ? Does it provide advantages for single-threaded scenarios ?

Comment: If you use the current thread executor, I think you have fewer restrictions on your futures, since they don't need to be `Send`.  With the threaded executor, all futures need to be `Send` even when you only use a single thread. (I may be mixing up the terminology, but it's something along these lines.)